# MS Dynamics CRM 2011 AND TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, dynamics-crm, dvcs

For business purpose, I need to get in touch with CRM 2011 (cf. 5.0) and TFS 2010 then try to see whether they can be integrated together or not. I've read something about TFS 2008 and CRM 2009 but couldn't find input related to CRM 2011 and TFS 2010.

Any suggestion, tip, pointer, trick, highlight... is welcome :)

Comment: Could you please describe what kind of integration you are looking for? Do you want to have an automated deployment with it or do you want to track customization changes?

Comment: Hi ckeller. Thank you for your hint :). And in fact, I'd like an automated deployment with it indeed, I need to find a way to *compile* the CRM solutions within TFS 2010 into one single solution file (or whatever possible) and then deploy it to a given server. Did you achieve this already ? If so, I'll be glad to hear some about it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

They are not, but you never know someone might come up with it soon. I know I will try :)

Comment: Yeah then keep us up to date on your attempts and I'll do so of course ;) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but there is [Microsoft Dynamics CRM & TFS Case Integration](http://www.quantumwhisper.com/dynamics-crm-microsoft-tfs-integration/) from [Quantum Whisper](http://www.quantumwhisper.com/). I didn't try it yet, though.